# Sklearn PCA: Different number of components for train and test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm using Sklearn's `PCA` to do dimensionality reduction.  I'm fitting and tranforming my input data, `X`, like this:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=0.9999)
final_X = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

This yields 13 features.  Then I apply this to my test set:

```
test_X = pca.fit_transform(test_1)
```

It only yields 9 features, which is problematic when I go to predict.  I'll have trained on data with 13 features and then test on data with 9 features (and no guarantee the 9 is a subset of the 13).

Should I be keeping track of *which* features PCA selects and then only keep those?

If so, how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `fit_transform()`. You should be calling `transform()` instead. More on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692740/5858851) to a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `transform` instead of `fit_transform` on test data so that the *training* and *testing* data are transformed in the same way (by the same `pca` model). `test_X = pca.transform(test_1)`