# what is the difference between fit() ,fit_transform() and transform() in scikit_learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

This is code for feature scaling in which i am using `fit_transform()` and `transform()`:

```
##Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x=StandardScaler()
X_train=sc_x.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=sc_x.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: You may find [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692740/5858851) to a similar question useful. Also related: [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838056/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-and-fit-transform-in-sklearn).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912149/5114585 explains in detail the difference and when to use which of these.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fit` means to fit the pre-processor to the data being provided. This is where the pre-processor "learns" from the data.

`transform` means to transform the data (produce outputs) according to the fitted pre-processor; it is normally used on the *test* data, and unseen data in general (e.g. in new data that come after deploying a model).

`fit_transform` means to do both - Fit the pre-processor to the data, then transform the data according to the fitted pre-processor. Calling `fit_transform` is a convenience to avoid needing to call `fit` and `transform` sequentially on the same input, but of course this is only applicable to the *training* data (calling again `fit_transform` in test or unseen data is unfortunately a common rookie mistake).

Comment: fit_transform is also advertised as more efficient by sklearn