# How to use fit and transform for training and testing data with StandardScaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

As shown in the code below, I am using the StandardScaler.fit() function to fit (i.e., calculate the mean and variance from the features) the training dataset. Then, I call the ".transform()" function to scale the features. I found in the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692500/fit-transform-on-training-data-and-transform-on-test-data) that I should use ".transform()" only to transform test dataset. In my case, I am trying to implement the anomaly detection model such that all training dataset is from one targeted user while all test dataset is collected from multiple other anomaly users. I mean, we have "n" users and we train the model using one class dataset samples from the targeted user while we test the trained model on new anamoly samples selected randomly from all other "n-1" anomaly users.

Training dataset size: (4816, 158) => (No of samples, No of features)
Test dataset size: (2380, 158)
The issue is the model gives bad results when I use fit() then "transform()" for the training dataset and only "transform()" for the test dataset. However, the model gives good results only when I use "fit_transform()" with both train and test datasets instead of only "transform()" for the test dataset.

My question:
Should I follow the documentation of StandardScaler such that the test dataset MUST be transformed only using ".transform()" without fit() function? Or it depends on the dataset such that I can use the "fit_transform()" function for both training and testing datasets?

Is it possible if I use "fit_transform" for both training and testing dataset?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


# After preparing and splitting the training and testing dataset, we got
X_train # from only the targeted user
X_test  # from other "n-1" anomaly users

# features selection using VarianceThreshold on training set
 sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
 X_train= sel.fit_transform(X_train)
#Normalization using StandardScaler
 scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
 normalized_X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
 set_printoptions(precision=3)
# features selection using VarianceThreshold on testing set

 X_test= sel.transform(X_test)
#Normalization using StandardScaler

 normalized_X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
 set_printoptions(precision=3)
```

Comment: What should I use with test data, "fit_transform()" or only "transform()"?

Comment: You mean should I use "fit_transform()" with training data, but with test data I use only "fit()" without transform? Are you sure, please?

Comment: @prhmma is wrong, you should only use `transform` on the test data. 
`X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train);X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)`

Never, ever, ever, ever, call `fit` on the test data.

Comment: @ amdex. Yes, you are right.  I tested the answer of prhmma and it is wrong. However, my question still not answered. Is it possible if I use "fit_transform" for both training and testing dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I follow the documentation of StandardScaler such that the test dataset MUST be transformed only using ".transform()" without fit() function? Or it depends on the dataset such that I can use the "fit_transform()" function for both training and testing datasets?

The moment you are re-training your scaler for the testing set you will have a different dependincy of your input features. The original algorithm will be fitted based on the fitting of your training sacling. And if you re-train it this will be overwritten, and you are faking your input of the test data for the algorithm.

So the answer is **MUST** only be transformed.

Answer (score 2):

The way you do it above is correct. You should, in principle, never use `fit` on test data, only on the train data. The fact that you get "better" results using `fit_transform` on the test data is not indicative of any real performance gains. In other words, by using `fit` on the test data, you lose the ability to say something meaningful about the predictive power of your model on unseen data.

The main lesson here is that any gains in test performance are meaningless once the methodological constraints (i.e. train-test separation) are violated. You may obtain higher scores using `fit_transform`, but these don't mean anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to transform a data you should declare that.
like:

```
data["afs"]=data["afs"].transform()
```